# Angular form validation not working inside a modal dialog

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-forms

I have a registration form inside a `modal` window from `ui-bootstrap` library. I am trying to get validations working on this form without any success. I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

here is link to plunker demonstrating same issue
http://plnkr.co/edit/9QUsvBWd0XAAryqtGUI1?p=preview

Comment: @DRobinson novalidate attribute is only preventing browser from showing ugly messages like "This is not an email". It doesn't prevent Angural from validating form.

Comment: Right, makes sense. Retracted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misspelled regForm - it was regFrom, see it's working now:
http://plnkr.co/edit/17Yaokycc3Xa0IeWr24M?p=preview

Correct span with error message:

```
<span style="color:red" ng-show="regForm.email.$dirty && regForm.email.$invalid">
    <span ng-show="regForm.email.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
    <span ng-show="regForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>
</span>
```